# Why is my flash's zoom stuck at 14mm?

Tags: flash, yongnuo

I am using a flash, the Yongnuo YN-568EXII for Canon, and am facing a zoom issue. It's stuck at 14mm and the M sign is blinking near the zoom button. I am not able to change the zoom. If anyone has any solution please share.

Answer (score 12):

Check that the diffusion panel is fully seated back into its slot.  Like the Canon flashes the YN-568EXII is imitating, if the diffusion panel is pulled out, the flash sets itself to the widest zoom and ignores any attempts to set the zoom differently.

Comment: This is one question where I felt SO should allow us to award extra votes or stars!! After reading this answer the line in page 18 of manual (`NOTE: Using wide-angle-diffuser, the flash coverage will then be extended for 14mm. `) makes perfect sense :)